# Web scraping macro works only on my computer

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have written a macro, which scrapes my company's intranet site for data to populate a sheet in Excel, that works just as it should on my computer, but when I share the macro with my colleagues, it throws a `Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)': Access is denied` error on their computers at the .send line.

All security settings are in place, macros enabled, references and versions are the same between our computers, we are all on the same network, have access to the site, etc.

Here is the part of my code that scrapes the site:

```vb
Do While i < lastRowScrape + 1
    For j = 0 To 5

       Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
       Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

       XMLPage.Open "GET", "[the site's url]", False
       XMLPage.send
       HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

       'grab data
       siteData = Trim(HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("title_list")(j).innerText)

       'populate cells
       Cells(j + i, 2).Value = siteData(1)
       Cells(j + i, 4).Value = siteData(0)
       Cells(j + i, 6).Value = siteData(2)
       Cells(j + i, 5).Value = siteData(3)

    Next j
    i = i + 6
Loop
```

Comment: it must be site access issue. try to open link manually.

Comment: also check network credentials is not the problem -login to their machines with your credentials and try it

Answer (score 0):

This could be a binding issue. In your code, you are using early binding which requires a project reference. Try using late binding in your declarations and see if that helps.

```
Dim XMLPage As New Object: Set XMLPage = MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 
Dim HTMLDoc As New Object: Set HTMLDoc = MSHTML.HTMLDocument
```